# Rails on Heroku, redacto editor display twice

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, redactor

In my development environment, everything is okay.

editor work so great.

but when app run on heroku, the WYSIWYG editor Redactor display twice.

one default style Redactor editor, and one custom style Redactor editor.

I try to delete custom setup,

not working,

it display two, two default style editor,

ban turbolinks or modify config, it's still not working.

wherever I do, I got two editor on the page where use Redactor.

on Heroku the page look like:

```
<div class="redactor-box">
  <ul class="redactor-toolbar" id="redactor-toolbar-2">
  </ul> 
  <div class="redactor-editor">  
  </div> 
  <div class="redactor-box">
    <ul class="redactor-toolbar" id="redactor-toolbar-3">
    </ul>
    <div class="redactor-editor">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my development env, it look like:

```
<div class="redactor-box">
  <ul class="redactor-toolbar" id="redactor-toolbar-2">
  </ul> 
  <div class="redactor-editor">  
  </div> 
</div>
```

this is my code.

```
#app/views/articles/new.html.erb


<div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-md-offset-2">
  <%= form_for([current_user, @article]) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', var: @article %>

    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', id: "article-title" %></br>

    <%= f.label :content %>

    <%= f.text_area :content, class: :redactor %></br>

    <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-default btn-custom" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

and this is my Redactor config.

```
#app/assets/javascripts/redactor-rails/config.js


window.init_redactor = function(){
  var csrf_token = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
  var csrf_param = $('meta[name=csrf-param]').attr('content');
  var params;
  if (csrf_param !== undefined && csrf_token !== undefined) {
      params = csrf_param + "=" + encodeURIComponent(csrf_token);
  }
  $('.redactor').redactor({

        "imageUpload":"/redactor_rails/pictures?" + params,
        "imageGetJson":"/redactor_rails/pictures",
        "fileUpload":"/redactor_rails/documents?" + params,
        "fileGetJson":"/redactor_rails/documents",
        "path":"/assets/redactor-rails",
        "css":"style.css",
        "minHeight" : 300
      });
}

$(document).on( 'ready page:load', window.init_redactor );
```

rails '4.2.3'

redactor-rails '0.5.0'

Thanks for read.

---

update

when I delete all config file, not just change some setup,

I got right display.

but if I do that, I can't custom my editor.

finally, I use CSS solve the problem.
it's a stupid way,

The extra editor just be hidden, not disappear.

```
    .fix-box { 
      margin-top: 110px;
      .redactor-box {
        #redactor-toolbar-2 {
          display: none;
        }
        .redactor-box {
          margin-top: -110px;
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change

```
$(document).on( 'ready page:load', window.init_redactor );
```

to

```
$(document).ready(function(){window.init_redactor});
```

pageLoad may be called more than once in some circumstances, causing multiple Redactor instances in your case